# Oblique asymptote of $f(x) = \frac{x\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x+2}}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, radicals, limits-without-lhopital

I've found the slope using $\lim_{x \to \infty } \frac{f(x)}{x}$ that is $1$ but I can't find the $h = \lim_{x \to \infty } f(x) - x$ . How we find $\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{x\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x+2}} - x$ if it exists ?

Also if there is another way for finding oblique asymptote , please write it .

Comment: HINT: $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x\sqrt x}{\sqrt{x+2}}-x=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x(\sqrt x-\sqrt{x+2})}{\sqrt{x+2}}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\left(\frac{x\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x+2}} - x\right)=-\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{2x}{(\sqrt{x+2}+\sqrt{x})\sqrt{x+2}}=$$
$$=-\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{2}{\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{2}{x}}+1\right)\sqrt{1+\frac{2}{x}}}=-1,$$
which gives $y=x-1$.

Comment: Why $-\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{2x}{(\sqrt{x+2}+\sqrt{x})\sqrt{x+2}}=-1$ ?

Comment: Yes, I explained it. See now.

Comment: I used $\frac{\sqrt{x+2}}{\sqrt{x}}=\sqrt{1+\frac{2}{x}}.$

Comment: Oh , sorry . I've made a terrible mistake . Thanks for the answer .

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{x\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x+2}} - x=\frac{x\sqrt{x}-x\sqrt{x+2}}{\sqrt{x+2}}\frac{x\sqrt{x}+x\sqrt{x+2}}{x\sqrt{x}+x\sqrt{x+2}}=\frac{x^3-x^3-2x^2}{\sqrt{x+2}(x\sqrt{x}+x\sqrt{x+2})}=\frac{-2x^2}{x\sqrt{x^2+2x}+x\sqrt{x^2+4x+4}}=\frac{-2x^2}{x^2\left(\sqrt{1+\frac2x}+\sqrt{1+\frac4x+\frac4{x^2}}\right)}\to\frac{-2}{2}=-1$$

Comment: Can you explain the last step ?

Comment: you simply take $x^2$ from denominator, I'll add this step

Comment: @S.H.W is it clear now?

Comment: Yes , thanks a lot .

Answer (score 1):

Alternative way. By using the Taylor expansion $(1+t)^a=1+at+o(t)$ as $t\to 0$, we can find the oblique asymptote in just one step: as $x\to +\infty$
$$f(x)=\frac{x\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x+2}}=x\left(1+\frac{2}{x}\right)^{-1/2}=x\left(1-\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{2}{x}+o(1/x)\right)=x-1+o(1).$$
Hence $\lim_{x\to +\infty}(f(x)-(x-1))=0$, which means that the oblique asymptote is $y=x-1$.

Comment: Brilliant ! Can you explain $o$ notation ? I searched over the internet but it was so confusing to understand .

Comment: @S.H.W This is the "little-o_notation". Take a look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation

Comment: @S.H.W To avoid the "little-o_notation" just use the fact that $\lim_{t\to 0}((1+t)^a-1)/t=a$.

Comment: Okay , thanks a lot .